# Cassandra Retry Policy for NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, exception, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, retrypolicy

I'm using the datastax Java cassandra driver (3.0.2) to connect to a cassandra cluster. **In case of a [NoHostAvailableException](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/NoHostAvailableException.html) i want to retry after some seconds**. Is is correct, that none of the predefined policies covers this requirement? 
I think i have to implement a custom Policy:

```
public class CustomRetryPolicy implements RetryPolicy {...}
```

- DefaultRetryPolicy

> This implementation triggers a maximum of one retry, and only if enough
>   replicas had responded to the read request but data was not retrieved
>   amongst those.

- DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy

> A retry policy that sometimes retries with a lower consistency level
>   than the one initially requested.

- FallThroughRetryPolicy

> A retry policy that never retries (nor ignores).

- LoggingRetryPolicy

> A retry policy that wraps another policy, logging the decision made by
>   its sub-policy

Comment: Sorry, but the linked answere did't answere the question if this retry policy for NoHostAvailableExeption is delivered by the java driver of datastax.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to retry on NoHostAvailableExeption, this exception is merely a container for a set of exceptions encountered when querying different hosts for one given request. The RetryPolicy applies to each one of these errors individually, not to NoHostAvailableExeption.